# php 2d array sort parent child

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, parent

Yes,yes I know, here is a bunch of questions about array sorting, but i need one more specific explanation.
I have a DB table to store multi-level menu with products.
Like: itemId, parentId, itemtitle, ...
I use this table to build menu on  webpage, using reccursive function and I want to use this DB-table to get data for backend html form, for option list.
Unsorted data from DB I need to sort correctly and put in json array.
Half part of work i done with this:

```
//empty arrays for sorting purposes  
$ids = array();
$parents = array();
// iterate, $items - unsorted array from DB 
foreach ($items as $key => $row) {
    $ids[$key]  = $row['itemId'];
    $parents[$key] = $row['parentId'];
}
// sorting
array_multisort($ids, SORT_ASC, $parents, SORT_ASC, $items);
//now $items partly sorted
```

FIG.1
So $items list looks like:
(itemId - parentId - itemTitle)
1 - 0 - ***A
2 - 0 - ***B
3 - 0 - ***C
4 - 0 - ***D
6 - 1 - ***E
7 - 1 - ***F
8 - 1 - ***G
9 - 2 - ***H
10 - 2 - ***I
11 - 2 - ***J
12 - 2 - ***K
13 - 2 - ***L
14 - 3 - ***M
15 - 3 - ***N
16 - 3 - ***O
17 - 4 - ***P
18 - 4 - ***Q

FIG.2
I need:
1 - 0 - ***A
6 - 1 - ***E
7 - 1 - ***F
8 - 1 - ***G
2 - 0 - ***B
9 - 2 - ***H
10 - 2 - ***I
11 - 2 - ***J
12 - 2 - ***K
13 - 2 - ***L
3 - 0 - ***C
14 - 3 - ***M
15 - 3 - ***N
16 - 3 - ***O
4 - 0 - ***D
17 - 4 - ***P
18 - 4 - ***Q

### So the question is - how convert array from FIG.1 to array from FIG.2 neat way?

So this i my soution. 2-level menu only:

```
    //get all categories, primary sorted by MySQL
    $items = $cataloAR->query("SELECT itemId, parentId,itemTitle FROM `catalog` ORDER BY parentId, itemId"); 
//pre-sort by - itemId, parentId
    $ids = array();//array for id`s
    $parents = array();//array for parents
// get columns list
    foreach ($items as $key => $row) {
        $ids[$key]  = $row['itemId'];
        $parents[$key] = $row['parentId'];
    }
// sort ascending by id, ascending by parent
    array_multisort($ids, SORT_ASC, $parents, SORT_ASC, $items);
//make emptyarray for sorteddata, like - $entryList['itemId']['itemTitle'] 
    $entryList = array();//empty array
    $len = count($items); //count elements for proceeding
    $currentEntry = 0;  //current element number,start from 0-element
//iterate
//while reaching last element in list
   while($currentEntry < $len){        
//if current element is empty => go to next element
        if (!isset($items[$currentEntry])) {
            $currentEntry++;
        } 
 //get current element from $items
//put it to $entryList
        $entryList[] = $items[$currentEntry];    
// get current id 
        $currentId = $items[$currentEntry]['itemId'];        
//remove element from  $items, because we just put it to the sorted list
        unset($items[$currentEntry]);     
//search in $items entries with  patternId = $items['itemId']  
//put to sorted list
//remove element 
        foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
            if($value['parentId'] == $currentId){
                $entryList[] = $value;               
                unset($items[$key]);                  
            } 
            if (!isset($value)){
                continue;
            }

        } 
//increase counter               
            $currentEntry++;                   
    }    
//purge sorted list from empty elements  $entryList
    $sortedList = array_filter($entryList);
 //Enjoy it!
    return $sortedList;
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some assumptions about your array and created it with the below code. I was able to replicate the desired output by creating two new arrays ($root and $menu), and then looping through each of them to build the menu. This was tricky, and the best answer would actually be to build this array differently from the beginning, but if that's not possible, this code should get you to where you need to be:

```
$items[] = array('itemId' => 1,'parentId' => 0,'itemTitle' => '***A');
$items[] = array('itemId' => 2,'parentId' => 0,'itemTitle' => '***B');
$items[] = array('itemId' => 3,'parentId' => 0,'itemTitle' => '***C');
$items[] = array('itemId' => 4,'parentId' => 0,'itemTitle' => '***D');
$items[] = array('itemId' => 6,'parentId' => 1,'itemTitle' => '***E');
$items[] = array('itemId' => 7,'parentId' => 1,'itemTitle' => '***F');
$items[] = array('itemId' => 8,'parentId' => 1,'itemTitle' => '***G');
$items[] = array('itemId' => 9,'parentId' => 2,'itemTitle' => '***H');
$items[] = array('itemId' => 10,'parentId' => 2,'itemTitle' => '***I');
$items[] = array('itemId' => 11,'parentId' => 2,'itemTitle' => '***J');
$items[] = array('itemId' => 12,'parentId' => 2,'itemTitle' => '***K');
$items[] = array('itemId' => 13,'parentId' => 2,'itemTitle' => '***L');
$items[] = array('itemId' => 14,'parentId' => 3,'itemTitle' => '***M');
$items[] = array('itemId' => 15,'parentId' => 3,'itemTitle' => '***N');
$items[] = array('itemId' => 16,'parentId' => 3,'itemTitle' => '***O');
$items[] = array('itemId' => 17,'parentId' => 4,'itemTitle' => '***P');
$items[] = array('itemId' => 18,'parentId' => 4,'itemTitle' => '***Q');

foreach ($items as $itemArray) {
    $parent = $itemArray['parentId'];
    $item = $itemArray['itemId'];
    $title = $itemArray['itemTitle'];

    if ($parent == 0) {
        // this is a root item
        $root[$item] = $title;
    } else {
        // this is a submenu item
        $menu[$parent][$item] = $title;
    }
}

foreach ($root as $key => $value) {
    // this is a root item, which is always 0.
    echo "$key, 0, $value <br/>";
    foreach ($menu as $parent => $item) {
        if ($parent == $key) {
            foreach ($item as $itemId => $title) {
                // output the submenu items under the root
                echo "$itemId, $parent, $title <br />";
            }
        }
    }
}
```